# Jest magic number comparison failing in expect...toBe

Tags: typescript, jestjs, magic-numbers

I'm testing to ensure a `Buffer`'s magic number is `zip` format.

I'm doing this by extracting the buffer's first 4 bytes to string and comparing against the magic number for zip which is `PK`.

```
   const zipMagicNumber: string = 'PK'
   const uploadedMagicNumber: string = uploadMock.mock.calls[0][0].Body.subarray(0, 4).toString()

   expect(zipMagicNumber).toBe(uploadedMagicNumber)
```

But the test is failing with:

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "PK"
    Received: "PK"
```

These are the both the same values and are both strings. Am I missing something?

Comment: `toBe` asks if they're the same reference. Try `toEqual`.

Comment: tried `toEqual` and it threw the same error

Answer (score 0):

Some hidden characters were causing the comparison error, so for legibility I moved to using hex comparisons instead and now it's passing:

```
const zipMagicNumber = Buffer.from('504B0304', 'hex').toString('hex')
const uploadedMagicNumber = uploadMock.mock.calls[0][0].Body.subarray(0, 4).toString('hex')

expect(zipMagicNumber).toBe(uploadedMagicNumber)
```